# Finding cause of jitter in collision detection

Tags: java, game-engine, collision, rounding, detection

I'm looking for help in finding the source of jitter when using collision detection.
I've implemented a java game (using eclipse and slick2d) and have been loosely following this guide:
http://katyscode.wordpress.com/2013/01/18/2d-platform-games-collision-detection-for-dummies

but of course changing bits where necessary to suit my game and java not cpp.

From the research I have done I think the root cause of my jitter is coming from rounding errors. 
Despite that being my main suspect, I still haven't been able to identify where it's occurring.

Sorry if the indentation isn't quite right there, had a little trouble using the code block recognition.

Basically I'm creating variables in the class.
In init() I set up most of the resources.
In render() all the drawing takes place. Note the graphics translation so the camera follows the player.
In update I'm of course updating the position of the player according to user input, gravity and friction.

I also call my collision detection from this method.
Collision detection is working on a penetration resolution method.

(Yes I know I'm exhaustively comparing with every single world object. I will be improving my efficiency with AABB's when I have sorted more fundamental problems out. Like jitter!)

My method first calculates how much the player expects to move in each axis, then for each world object it checks for intersection with the players bounding points (floating point values that represent coordinates around the player). It checks this in each direction and uses the result to determine in which axis the collision occurred, if any, so that the appropriate action can be taken.

Sorry it's a put load of code, but it's collision detection after all, which isn't a small thing.

Here is my Play class where all the updating goes on for the game:

```
package GameFiles;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
//import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class Play extends BasicGameState{

    static int tileSize = 32;
    File levelMap;
    SpriteSheet spriteSheet;
    int[][] currentMap;
    Image[] groundTiles = new Image[4];
    //List<Rectangle2D> levelBounds = new ArrayList<Rectangle2D>();
    List<Rectangle> levelBounds = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    Player player;
    float playerX, playerY;
    int dir;
    float acc, mov, friction, gravity;
    float runSpeed;
    float maxAcc;
    boolean inAir, jumping, keyDown;
    boolean exitFlag;
    int mapHeight, mapWidth;
    float mapX, mapY;
    float speedX, speedY;
    int worldObjectCount;
    int iterations;

public Play(int state){

}

public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException{
    playerX = Game.scrWidth/2;
    playerY = Game.scrHeight - tileSize - tileSize;
    player = new Player(playerX, playerY);
    levelMap = new File("maps/lvl1.txt");
    spriteSheet = new SpriteSheet("res/tiles/tilesets/DungeonCrawlTilesetBW.png", tileSize, tileSize);

    try 
    {
        currentMap = readMap(levelMap);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Array size mismatch when copying arrays.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    levelBounds.clear();
    for(int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++){
            if(currentMap[x][y] == 1){
                levelBounds.add(new Rectangle(x*tileSize, Game.scrHeight - mapHeight*tileSize + y*tileSize, tileSize, tileSize));
                //levelBounds.add(new Rectangle2D.Float(x*tileSize, Game.scrHeight - mapHeight*tileSize + y*tileSize, tileSize, tileSize));
                System.out.println("Added new bounding box: " + (x*tileSize) + ", " + (Game.scrHeight - mapHeight*tileSize + y*tileSize) + ", " + tileSize);
            }
        }
    }
    worldObjectCount = levelBounds.size();
    System.out.println("World object count: " + worldObjectCount);

    groundTiles[0] = spriteSheet.getSubImage(4, 16);
    groundTiles[1] = spriteSheet.getSubImage(13, 19);

    dir = 1;
    acc = 0.0f;
    mov = 0.0f;
    friction = 4f;
    gravity = 4f;
    runSpeed = 0.6f;
    maxAcc = -1f;
    inAir = false;
    jumping = false;
    keyDown = false;
    exitFlag = false;
    speedX = 0.0f;
    speedY = 0.0f;
    iterations = 3;
}

public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException{

    //determine cameraX and cameraY
    float cameraX, cameraY;
    cameraX = player.getX() - Game.scrWidth/2;
    cameraY = player.getY() - (Game.scrHeight/2 - tileSize - tileSize);
    g.translate(-cameraX, -cameraY);
    player.render(g);

    for(int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++){
            if(currentMap[x][y] == 1){
                groundTiles[0].draw(x*tileSize, Game.scrHeight - mapHeight*tileSize + y*tileSize);
            }
        }
    }
    g.translate(cameraX, cameraY);
}

public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException{
    Input input = gc.getInput();
    float secondsElapsed = delta/1000.0f;
    checkCollisions(secondsElapsed);


    player.setX((player.getX() + speedX));
    player.setY((player.getY() - speedY));

    //check inputs
    checkKeyEvents(input);

    //slow down / friction
    if(!keyDown){
        if(mov < 0)
            mov += friction * secondsElapsed;
        else
            mov -= friction * secondsElapsed;
    }
    speedX = mov;
    if (speedX > 0 && speedX < friction * secondsElapsed) speedX = 0;
    if (speedX < 0 && speedX > -friction * secondsElapsed) speedX = 0;


    //jump or fall
    acc -= gravity * secondsElapsed;
    if (acc < maxAcc){
        acc = maxAcc;
    }
    speedY = acc;

    //exit when exitFlag true
    if(exitFlag){
        gc.exit();
    }
}

public void checkCollisions(float secondsElapsed){
    boolean contactX = true, contactYbottom = true, contactYtop = true;
    // Keep iterating the contact solver until the maximum number of iterations is reached
    // or no collisions are detected
    for (int iteration = 0; iteration < iterations && (contactX || contactYbottom || contactYtop); iteration++)
    {
        float nextMoveX = speedX * secondsElapsed;
        float nextMoveY = speedY * secondsElapsed;
        contactX = contactYbottom = contactYtop = false;
        float projectedMoveX, projectedMoveY, originalMoveX, originalMoveY;
        originalMoveX = nextMoveX;
        originalMoveY = nextMoveY;
        for (int o = 0; o < worldObjectCount && !contactX && !contactYbottom && !contactYtop; o++)
        {
            for (int dir = 0; dir < 6; dir++)
            {
                //top, bottom, left, left, right, right.
                if (dir == 0 && nextMoveY < 0) continue;
                if (dir == 1 && nextMoveY > 0) continue;
                if (dir == 2 && nextMoveX > 0) continue;
                if (dir == 3 && nextMoveX > 0) continue;
                if (dir == 4 && nextMoveX < 0) continue;
                if (dir == 5 && nextMoveX < 0) continue;
                projectedMoveX = (dir >= 2? nextMoveX : 0);
                projectedMoveY = (dir <  2? nextMoveY : 0);

                float[][] collisionPoint = player.getBounds();

                Rectangle curRect = new Rectangle(levelBounds.get(o).x, levelBounds.get(o).y, levelBounds.get(o).width, levelBounds.get(o).height);
                //Rectangle2D curRect = levelBounds.get(o).getBounds2D();

                while (curRect.contains(collisionPoint[dir][0] + projectedMoveX, collisionPoint[dir][1] + projectedMoveY)
                        || curRect.intersects(collisionPoint[dir][0] + projectedMoveX, collisionPoint[dir][1] + projectedMoveY, 1, 1))
                {
                    if (dir == 0) projectedMoveY += 0.05f; //top collision
                    if (dir == 1) projectedMoveY -= 0.05f; //bottom collision

                    if (dir == 2) projectedMoveX += 0.05f; //left collision
                    if (dir == 3) projectedMoveX += 0.05f;

                    if (dir == 4) projectedMoveX -= 0.05f; //right collision
                    if (dir == 5) projectedMoveX -= 0.05f;
                }

                if (dir >= 2 && dir <= 5) 
                    nextMoveX = projectedMoveX;
                if (dir >= 0 && dir <= 1) 
                    nextMoveY = projectedMoveY;
            }

            if (nextMoveY > originalMoveY && originalMoveY != 0)
            {
                contactYtop = true;
            }

            if (nextMoveY < originalMoveY && originalMoveY != 0)
            {
                contactYbottom = true;
            }

            if (Math.abs(nextMoveX - originalMoveX) > 0.01f)
            {
                contactX = true;
            }
            if (contactX && contactYtop && speedY > 0)
                speedY = nextMoveY = 0;
        }
        if (contactYbottom || contactYtop)
        {
            player.setY(player.getY() + nextMoveY);
            speedY = 0;
            acc = 0;
            if (contactYbottom)
                jumping = false;
        }

        if (contactX)
        {
            player.setX(player.getX() + nextMoveX);
            speedX = 0;
            mov = 0;
        }
    }//end collisions
}

public int[][] readMap(File level) throws IOException, SlickException{

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(level));

    mapWidth = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    mapHeight = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int[][] map = new int[mapWidth][mapHeight];

    for(int row = 0; row < mapHeight; row++)
    {
        String line = br.readLine();
        if(line == null || line.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Line is empty or null");
        }
        else
        {
            String[] tileValues = line.split(",");
            for(int col = 0; col < mapWidth; col++)
            {
               map[col][row] = Integer.parseInt(tileValues[col]);  

            }
        }
    }
    br.close();
    return map;
}

public void checkKeyEvents(Input input){
    //key input events
    if(input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_DOWN)){

    }
    if(input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_UP)){
        if(!jumping){
            acc = 1f;
        }
        jumping = true;
    }
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT) && !input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)){
        keyDown = false;
        mov -= 0.006f;
        if (mov < -runSpeed){
            mov = -runSpeed;
        }

    }
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT) && !input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)){
        keyDown = false;
        mov += 0.006f;
        if (mov > runSpeed){
            mov = runSpeed;
        }
    }
    if(input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_ESCAPE)){
        exitFlag = true;
    }
}

public int getID(){
    return 1;
}
```

}

Since I can't predict what more info a potential helper might need, I'll leave it at that for now, but of course I can provide any more info when/where needed.

Thanks,
J.

Comment: And the irony of asking for help having been following a guide "for dummies" is not lost on me. Fear not...

Comment: When does the jittering happen? While walking? While falling? While walking agains a wall?